# undefined method `symbolize_keys', Image_tag and link_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

`<%= link_to(image_tag ("Logo.png"), root_url) %>`

What am i doing wrong here? I have looked at all the related stackoverflow questions and docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the space after `image_tag`:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("Logo.png"), root_url) %>
```

Otherwise Ruby assumes that you want to call

```
image_tag "Logo.png", root_url
```

Comment: Didn't realize a space could make all the difference!